# If/else statement in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to change the inputLanguage that I input into the value 'en'. When I tried this method, the error that they return is english is not defined.

Here is my alchemy.js

```
    module.exports = function(Alchemy) {
 Alchemy.language = function(inText, inputLanguage, outputLanguage, cb) {
    console.log('Input text is ' + inText);
    console.log('Input language is ' + inputLanguage);
    console.log('Output language is ' + outputLanguage);
    getCode(inputLanguage, outputLanguage, cb);
  }

  Alchemy.remoteMethod(
    'language', {
      http: {
        path: '/language',
        verb: 'get'
      },
      accepts: [{
        arg: 'inText',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      }, {
        arg: 'inputLanguage',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      }, {
        arg: 'outputLanguage',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      }],
      returns: {
        arg: 'results',
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
  );
  function getCode(inputLanguage, outputLanguage, cb) {
      if (inputLanguage = english) {
          inLang = en;
          console.log('Input language is ' + inlang)
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: You have loads of syntax errors in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problems are in block`if (inputLanguage = english)`

First, `english` is undefined variable, so define it, or if you want change it to string, add quotation marks.

Second issue is `=` sign, single `=` is assigment, if you want to compare variable, then you need to use `==` or `===`

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing how `if`, variables and strings work. There is neither a variable called `english`, nor `en` -- and `=` assigns, `==` or `===` are checking for equality => [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript).

Try it with below:

```
if (inputLanguage === 'english') {
      inLang = 'en';
      console.log('Input language is ' + inlang)
}
```

In JS, strings are enclosed by `"` or `'`